# Callback oauth2Login()/re-login Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, vaadin

I want to re-login after token expires, I can't find suitable examples and resolve that.

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(SecurityUtils::isFrameworkInternalRequest).permitAll()
                .accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager())
                .and()
                .addFilterAfter(expiredTokenFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        super.configure(http);

        http
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(new CustomAccessDeniedHandler())
                .and()
                .oauth2Login(oauth2Login -> oauth2Login
                        .successHandler(new VaadinSavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                        .userInfoEndpoint(userInfoEndpointConfig -> userInfoEndpointConfig.oidcUserService(oidcUserService)))
                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler())
                        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", "GET"))
                );
    }
```

Comment: You don't have to relogin, the token is only used to login once. After you are logged in, you have a HTTP session, which will only expire if you don't send any further HTTP requests.

Comment: @dur, yeas, but I have Instant expiresAt field in token, I will to check that and relogin like this
`   boolean isExpired = Instant.now().compareTo(expiresAt) > 0;
                    System.out.println("isExpired: " + isExpired);
                    if (isExpired) {
                        refresh();
                    }`

Comment: So your token expires in less than 5 seconds? Then you should add some time.

Comment: @dur I have 1800 seconds. Where do you see 5 seconds?

Comment: Why do you need 1800 seconds to login? That should be less than 5 seconds. The authorization server is returning the token and den Oauth2 client is authenticating the session. How slow is your network? One request should not last 30 minutes.